# pass a link in a webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying when someone click for example : eee.com , to open it in my Webview app

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    public static WebView webView;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.eee.com/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.contains("eee.com")) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
       webView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
    }
```

but the app crashes on open it right away , I tried this :  :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
        if(getIntent().getData() != null){
            webView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
        }

    }
```

app works but on link click it just open the app without passing the link

Answer (score 0):

I solved it my self with :

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Uri x = intent.getData();
        webView.loadUrl(x.toString());
    }
```